# angular 15 module-federation Style not working

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue with my Angular microfrontend project where I'm facing the following error related to styles. I am using Angular 15 with the @angular-architects/module-federation/webpack library for microfrontend development.

I had a problem adding global styles in remote apps. To resolve this issue, I imported style.scss into the shared module in remote app.

In Angular 14, everything was fine, and the projects worked smoothly. However, when I upgraded my Angular projects to version 15, I encountered an error.

Here's my webpack.config.js file:

```
const { withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const shareAll = mf.shareAll;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.json"), []);
const webpackConfig = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'shareholders',
  exposes: {
    './PagesModule': './src/app/pages/pages.module.ts'
  },
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },
});

module.exports = {
  ...webpackConfig,
  output: {
    uniqueName: "remoteapp1",
    publicPath: "auto",
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    },
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

And here's the error message:

```
**File was processed with these loaders: *
./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js *
./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js.
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these
loaders.**
```

This is the [sample code](https://github.com/GuruNadh552/Micro-Frontends-in-Angular/tree/master) for my remote apps.

I want my remote apps' styles to work without relying on a style library.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into what might be causing this issue, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you!